# What causes the triangle lap time notification?

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

In Forza 3, there's an icon I colloquially call the "slop" icon. It looks something like this:

[image: Apparently some users are Unicode impaired?]

I've figured out a few of the conditions for it, but a few more elude me. This definitely seems to happen whenever you collide with any other car, the walls, an obstacle, etc. (Including just a quick rub.)

But other times ... I swear I've seen it come up when I've had no contact with anything and have stayed on the track. I've seen laps start with it when the previous lap had it.

What are the conditions for this notification? It's not really detailed in the manual.

Comment: Is it supposed to look like a box? Going by you saying "triangle" in the title, I'm assuming not, so if it isn't, I suggest using an image instead of the Unicode (perhaps just screenshot that text, haha ♪)

Comment: Updated for the Unicode-impaired.

Comment: Now I can't see it, because I have image sites blocked at work :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Forza forums:

> Certification guide:
>
> Forza 3 contains two different types
>   of lap times. Certified and
>   uncertified. Certified times are
>   always ranked higher than uncertified
>   times, no matter how fast they are.
>
> To uncertify your times, there are a
>   few things that could happen:
>
> ```
> Go off track
> Hit a wall
> Hit another car
> Draft in front or behind another car at over 100mph
> Rewind
> ```
>
> One other thing that can uncertify
>   your times is doing something to
>   uncertify in the last sector of a lap.
>   This will uncertify the next lap as
>   well.
>
> There is one source of confusion, and
>   that is whether bottoming out
>   uncertifies your lap or not. In my
>   experience, it does not. Bear in mind,
>   on Le Mans, it is very easy to
>   uncertify by driving outside the white
>   lines, even though you are still on
>   the tarmac. This is not a glitch, so
>   try to be careful.
>
> Drift Certification
>
> There are two things that will
>   uncertify a Drift lap:
>
> ```
> Going backwards
> Using rewind
> ```

This lines up with what I remember about the game, although I've not played in a while.

Comment: +1, but I'm still calling it the slop icon. :)

Comment: Also ... why would drafting over 100 decertify you? I mean, I *guess* it's a bit dangerous, but really, drafting is a part of (at least some kinds of) racing ...

Comment: I think it's because it involves interacting with other cars... it's not a "pure" lap time; you can't reproduce it e.g. on a time trial. (I didn't realise it was only over 100; maybe under 100 drafting doesn't actually do anything.) But then, as you say, real racing has best lap times, including drafting...